# spring+springmvc+mybatis not commit

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm new here, and now I put up Spring project by myself. It can work, and "select" is ok. But when I "insert" , the Eclipse console show this:

```
20190914:20:45:50.052 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG  Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2f70fe8]
20190914:20:45:50.053 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG  Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2f70fe8]
20190914:20:45:50.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG  Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2f70fe8]
20190914:20:45:50.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG  Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2f70fe8]
```

I think the "insert" is ok. But there's no data in my database!!! And here's my code:

service (It has impl, I'm lazy :P):

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public interface TaskService {

    void saveTask(List<Task> taskList);

}
```

mapper:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

@Mapper
public interface TaskMapper {

    public void saveTask(@Param("taskList") List<Task> taskList);
}
```

application.xml add TransactionManager, too:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kingdee.bfyj.ts" />
```

Why there is no data in database??
THX
(sry for my english :P)

Comment: Add the implementation of the service and the mapper xml to the question. Interfaces are not enough to see if implementation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

oh, is not the java's question. I use the MySQL Workbench, and when I click the "Commit the current transaction", it has the data